# Displaying content of term reference instead of link (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-field-api

I need help with this Drupal 7 situation:

- I'm publishing travel agency offers using my own content type named "offer"
- I'm storing information about hotels (descriptions, prices, photos, etc.) in taxonomy named "hotel"
- I need to display relevant hotel info in each offer

And here is my problem. I've added a new term reference field named "field_hotel", but I only get a link to taxonomy term instead of actual content.

I tried to use this code, entity_load() runs fine, but I get "EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids()" error in field_view_field(().

```
$term = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array($hotel["und"][0]["taxonomy_term"]->tid));     
$view = field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_hotel');    
print render($view);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing hotel information in taxonomy terms, I'd suggest that you create a separate content type for hotels. That way, you'll be able to link offers to hotels using [References](http://drupal.org/project/references), which is a much more flexible approach. That will also allow you to display hotel information on the offer page using Views.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the second line with `$view = taxonomy_term_view($term);`
See [documentation for `taxonomy_term_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view/7).